# Marchand balun layout

Tags: layout, electromagnetic, ads, balun

For [this marchand balun schematics in ADS](https://github.com/promach/marchand_balun), how to ***instruct*** the ADS layout generator to use coil shape (for area saving in IC) ?

Besides, anyone have any experience with [planar layout of marchand balun on PCB](http://sci-hub.tw/https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1516893) ?

**balun schematics**

[image: balun schematics]

**generated balun layout not in coil shape**

[image: generated balun layout not in coil shape]

**balun layout in coil shape**

[image: balun layout in coil shape]

Comment: I think you'll need to draw the coil shape manually and then optimize the balun performance (manually) using co-simulation.

Comment: @AndrésMartínezMera [http://edadocs.software.keysight.com/display/ads2009/Layout+Components+for+Momentum](EM/Circuit Co-simulation) ?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no instruction to convert coupled lines into their lumped  circuit equivalent in ADS, so you'll have to do it manually, draw the inductors in the layout window, and then run the EM simulation. Personally, I tend to use the co-simulation option (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQUfZNanNFk) because I consider this speeds the design cycle (change things in the layout <=> simulate circuit).

Comment: @AndrésMartínezMera Someone else told me to replace [CLIN](http://edadocs.software.keysight.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5918233) with [2 Symmetrical Coupled Microstrip Lines (MCP)](http://edadocs.software.keysight.com/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=5908451#content/view/7528727) and then use linecalc to get the correct length and width.

What do you think about this idea ?

Comment: That approach is correct too. I thought you were trying to implement the lumped equivalent circuit of the Marchand balun. At which frequency should your design work?

Comment: @AndrésMartínezMera I just realized that MCP will only result in straight line layout. The balun working frequency is 60GHz. I do not have tapeout opportunity currently, I could only do it on PCB layout. Would 60GHz work for PCB layout